# How do I increment emails by 1 when I Save As in a directory?

Tags: vba, increment, save-as

I've had the hardest time figuring out the below code

I am trying to save many files over the course of a day into one directory with the same name, except with a number that marks it in a successive fashion.

I have searched stackoverflow, but cannot seem to understand where I put the Save As line, within the loop to increment by one? Well, that didn't work and neither did many other tries.

Please kindly advise on this :)

```
Sub AutoSave()

     Dim filename As String, filepath As String, filecount As Integer, filedate 
     As String

     filedate = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")

     filepath = "C:\Users\nabil\OneDrive\Documents"

     filecount = filecount + 1

     Set book = Workbooks.Open("Nabil 06-06-2019 #1 Lincoln.xlsx")

' code to copy and paste here

     If Len(Dir(filepath & filename)) <> 0 Then

     filecount = filecount + 1

     filename = "Nabil " & filedate & " " & "#" & filecount & " " & "Lincoln"

     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _ "C:\Users\nabil\OneDrive\Documents\Nabil 
     " & filedate & " " & "#" & filecount & " " & "Lincoln" & ".xlsx"

     End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help Mathieu. I have now edited it like this above

But now it does not want to Save As , when I put the save as in the loop or if-then statement. If I put it after the loop , then it prompts me to save over the existing file name, not saving as the file name with an increment of 1 (.e.g, #2)

This is a sliver of the code I'm using which requires that I operate from the macro workbook and open a blank template and paste data onto it , and then save as throughout the day

Please kindly advise :)

Comment: Shouldn't `Workbooks.Open` and `Workbook.SaveAs` be *within* the loop? Put everything you want to happen *for each workbook* inside the loop body

Comment: Suggestion: `Dim book As Workbook`, then `Set book = Workbooks.Open(...)` - and then you can do `book.SaveAs ...` and `book.Close`, and then with `Dim summarySheet As Worksheet` and `Set summarySheet = book.Worksheets("Summary")` you can manipuate *that* worksheet, without ever needing to `Select` or `Activate` any sheet or workbook!

Comment: `FileName` needs to be in the loop body too - `Dir(filepath & filename))` is constant for every iteration, ...there's only 1 file by that name.